# Create a class that can handle all type of CRUD Operation. No need to make SessionFactory or Session Object Each Time I need to do CRUD

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I want to make a class in java have a method that can interact with Hibernate configuration and do certain operation is identified as ENUM (eg: read, update, add, delete and etc.)

Method Parameters should be (Enum operations, class DTO, NamedQuery namedquery ,DTOObject Object_to_persist, param(any extra argument)).

Method should be as convenient that i can call it whenever i need by Passing actual argument(Operation.read, USERDTO.class , namedquery , USERDTO obj_UserDTO , HashMap hmapData).

```
  /* Enum Defined Operation done to the database.
   */ 
     public enum Operations {READ,UPDATE,ADD,DELETE};

      /*Centralized Method Defination for Basic CRUD Operation */
public T<?> DatabaseCRUDOperations((Operation.READ,USERDTO.class , namedquery , USERDTO obj_UserDTO , HashMap<String, String> hmapid){
     switch(Operation opts){
             case Operation.Read : //Call Read Method
               break;

             case Operation.UPDATE: //call Update Method
               break;
                ......
                ......
              default://call any Error Method or set error
        }
   }
```

Basically i want to define a custom Class (one kind of internal Framework for project) which have all basic CRUD Operation should done via this Class only. No need to create SessionFactory or Session Object Create every Where i Need.
Please Suggest by some code-snipt.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, have a look to [Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.2.RELEASE/reference/html/)

Comment: sorry u didn't get my point. I used Hibernate configuration But what i want to do is create a method that can handle all dto and do stuff as operations (enum) is passed to parameter..
I try to do just for my convenience .. Bydway Thanks for participating

Answer (score 2):

Java Generics to the rescue! Prepare to be amazed.

Your abstract entity (useful if you want to define methods to use in things like, for example, generic controller classes):

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<ID extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    public abstract ID getPrimaryKey();//I simply put this here as an example
}
```

Create the generic DAO interface:

```
public interface IGenericDAO<T extends AbstractEntity<ID>, ID extends Serializable> {
    T findByPrimaryKey(ID id);

    T save(T entity);

    void delete(T entity);

    List<T> saveAll(List<T> entities);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then, define your abstract generic DAO:

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDAO<T extends AbstractEntity<ID>, ID extends Serializable> implements IGenericDAO<T, ID> {
    protected Class<T> persistentClass;

    protected AbstractHibernateDAO(){}
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public AbstractHibernateDAO(Class c) {
        persistentClass = c;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T findByPrimaryKey(ID id){
        return (T) HibernateUtil.getSession().get(persistentClass, id);
    }


    @Override
    public T save(T entity){
        HibernateUtil.getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> saveAll(List<T> entities){
        for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++){
            HibernateUtil.getSession().saveOrUpdate(entities.get(i));
        }
        return entities;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T entity){
        HibernateUtil.getSession().delete(entity);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

DAO interface for entity (For this example, I'm using Integer as the primary key):

```
public interface IMyEntityDAO extends IGenericDAO<MyEntity, Integer> {
}
```

Now (drum roll), you are ready to lay some concrete (classes)...

DAO:

```
public class MyEntityDAO extends AbstractHibernateDAO<MyEntity, Integer> implements IMyEntityDAO {
    public MyEntityDAO() {
        super(MyEntity.class);
    }
}
```

MyEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity_table")
public class MyEntity extends AbstractEntity<Integer>{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "index")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

 public Integer getPrimaryKey (){
       return id;
 }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Boom. (Mic drop)

Let me know if you need further explanation!

I can't rightfully post this without giving credit to Cameron McKenzie and his amazing [book here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0615201954) . Which opened my eyes to a whole new world realizing the power of generics.